# Cookies didn't work correctly when login

Tags: session, cookies, authentication

I have checklogin.php page contain this code -:

```
if($re=="on"){
          setcookie("username",$myusername,time()+(86400*10));
          header("location:../index.php");
          }
      else{
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $myusername;
          $_SESSION['MM_Password'] = $mypassword; 
          header("location:../index.php");
          }
```

"re" is checkbox of remember me.
the page index.php start with-:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])){
     $username=$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
     $password= $_SESSION['MM_Password'];
     $sql1="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
     $result1=mysqli_query($berikane,$sql1);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
     $count1=mysqli_num_rows($result1);
     }
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
     $username=$_COOKIE['username'];
     $sql1="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ";
     $result1=mysqli_query($berikane,$sql1);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
     $count1=mysqli_num_rows($result1);
     }
 $myusername = $row['username'];
 $mypassword=$row['password'];
 if ($count1==0){
     header("Location: login/index.php");    
     }
else {
     }
```

It is login correctly if i didn't check "remember me" checkbox but when i check it cannot login

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this script -:

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie("username",$myusername,time()+31556926, '/', $domain, false );
```